# What could be the reason for Unable to start Content Delivery Component, could not locate Tridion Home Location

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Please suggest what could be the reason for below issue:

**Unable to start Content Delivery Component, could not locate Tridion Home Location, determined by presence of cd_core.jar cd_model.jar and (cd_broker_conf.xml or cd_storage_conf.xml) configuration files**

I can see Tridion_home variable is defined in environment variable, and if I echo %tridion_home% it gives my tridion home path.

Would appreciate for any help!!

Thanks.

Best Regards,
MS

**EDIT: I actual error generated while I am trying to get linking is below:**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking
================================================

Some configured classpath roots cannot be found

================================================

   ClassPath           : D:\www\IBETEST\bin\bin

============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

============================================================
```

Comment: Did you verify everything as suggested by the error message?

Comment: Yes, even we get in touch with tridion consultants and also looked the server....still giving same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error message states that tridion_home is determined to be valid if  cd_core.jar cd_model.jar and (cd_broker_conf.xml or cd_storage_conf.xml) configuration files exist in the path.  So when you echo %tridion_home% verify that the jars and config files are shown in the path.  If they are missing, then make sure to put the in the lib folder of the appropriate server role.

Comment: The jars should be in %TRIDION_HOME%\lib, the config files should be in %TRIDION_HOME%\config.

Comment: Hi Guys, Can you please look into above issue again, I have updated my question with more error details.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing JAR files or configuration files in that location, so it ruled it out as a valid Tridion home.

Have a look at this blog post of mine for more details on how the Tridion home directory is located: [How Tridion Content Delivery loads configuration files (.NET)](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/how-tridion-content-delivery-loads-configuration-files-in-dotnet)